# How to plot a histogram of one column colored by another in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, visualization, data-visualization

I have a dataset that contains, among other columns, 3 columns titled `Gender` (either `M` or `F`), `House` (either `A` or `B` or `C`), and `Indicator` (either 0 or 1). I want to plot the histogram of House `A` colored by Gender. This is my code to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', usecols=['House','Gender','Indicator')

A = df[df['House']=='A']
A = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['Indicator', 'Gender'])
```

This imports the values of House A for the respective genders correctly, as shown by its contents:

```
print(A)
            Indicator    Gender
0                   1      Male
1                   1      Male
2                   1      Male
4                   1    Female
7                   1      Male
8                   1      Male
11                  1      Male
14                  1      Male
17                  1      Male
18                  1    Female
19                  1    Female
20                  1    Female
21                  1      Male
24                  1      Male
26                  1    Female
27                  1      Male
...               ...       ...
```

Now when I want to plot the histogram of A colored by gender the way I did in MATLAB, it gives an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(A)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-81c3aef1748b> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.hist(A)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3130                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   3131                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 3132                       stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs)
   3133     finally:
   3134         ax._hold = washold

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
   6512             for xi in x:
   6513                 if len(xi) > 0:
-> 6514                     xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
   6515                     xmax = max(xmax, xi.max())
   6516             bin_range = (xmin, xmax)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amin(a, axis, out, keepdims)
     27 
     28 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 29     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
     30 
     31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

It seems we need to specify the exact column we want to make histogram of. It can't automatically understand (unlike MATLAB) that it needs to color according to the other column. So, doing the following plots the histogram, but with no color indicating the Gender:

```
plt.hist(A['Indicator'])
```

[image]

So, how do I make either a stacked histogram, or a side-by-side one colored by gender? Something like this, except there'll be only 2 bars for each Indicator, at x=0 and x=1:

```
x = np.random.randn(1000, 2)

colors = ['red', 'green']
plt.hist(x, color=colors)
plt.legend(['Male', 'Female'])
plt.title('Male and Female indicator by gender')
```

[image]

I have tried to imitate the above by copying the 2 dataframe columns into 2 columns of a list, and then trying to plot the histogram:

```
y=[]
y[0] = A[A['Gender'=='M']].tolist()
y[1] = A[A['Gender'=='F']].tolist()
plt.hist(y)
```

But this gives the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3062             try:
-> 3063                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3064             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-138cb74b6e00> in <module>()
      2 A= pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['Indicator', 'Gender'])
      3 y=[]
----> 4 y[0] = A[A['Gender'=='M']].tolist()
      5 y[1] = A[A['Gender'=='F']].tolist()
      6 plt.hist(y)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2683             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2684         else:
-> 2685             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2686 
   2687     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2690         # get column
   2691         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2692             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2693 
   2694         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2484         res = cache.get(item)
   2485         if res is None:
-> 2486             values = self._data.get(item)
   2487             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2488             cache[item] = res

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3063                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3064             except KeyError:
-> 3065                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3066 
   3067         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work, not tested with your data though.

```
genders = A.Gender.unique()
plt.hist([A.loc[A.Gender == x, 'Indicator'] for x in genders], label=genders)
```

Your code fails on `A[A['Gender'=='M']]` because it should be `A[A['Gender'] == 'M']` to get the Male elements, but you also need to select the column that you want.

Comment: Yeah, it works. Though I had to remove the `labels=genders`, as it was giving an attribute error, and put a separate line `plt.legend(genders)`. But I don't understand why it works or how, and why the code I posted doesn't.

Comment: I have updated my answer so that the label attribute is correct and also explained why your code isn't working